# BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@a34f859

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a mobile application using android and Firebase from a while but only now i encounter some problems as you can see here

```
I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms:com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@f3584ed
```

In addition, keep in mind already add users when i testing the app and i verified the e-mail and password as you can see :
[image]

here is my app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'    

/...

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

//firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'

implementation files('libs/ojdbc14.jar')
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M1'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1.3'
}
```

project gradle:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they  belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

my problem is when i sign in with registred and verified user, here is my sign in function:

```
private void verifyLogin(View view) {

    if ( !ValidatePassword()  || !ValidateEmail()){
        return;
    }

    final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    String email= login_email_field.getText().toString();
    String password= login_password_field.getText().toString();
    Log.d("password", password);
    Log.d("email", email);

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()){

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PublicHomeActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);


                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: U have firebase auth added twice in build.gradle

Comment: @PeterHaddad , I removed it but still same problem !

Comment: That log message is not an error.  You can tell because it starts with "I", which means it's just for information.  If your code isn't working the way you expect, please edit it to explain in more detail what's it's doing and how that's different than what you want.

Comment: My problem is i use firebase to verify mail and phone numbe, the register step that pass by verifing e-mail and phone is runned successfully and user is added when i verify in firebase console. still the problem when i logged on by verifed user can't access to  his account and i shared the signin method ! @DougStevenson

Comment: I solve it by removing this line:

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);